Docker cp command error
I'm trying to do an activity in Docker that my teacher requested but I'm having difficulty completing it.
He asked to create 3 containers, one of them called "webserver" and to upload a folder containing a website's files into this container and then run the website at localhost:8080.
But I'm having trouble uploading the folder to the container, here's what I did:
docker cp D:\site\spering-html webserver:/usr/share/nginx/html

the folder I want to upload is located on my pendrive D: and inside the site folder. I also tried the command
docker cp D:\site\spering-html\. webserver:/usr/share/nginx/html

adding a . in the end, but regardless of what I did the terminal always returned: copying between containers is not supported. I just can't identify the error, could someone explain it to me?
Note: translated text

Are you using windows CMD to run docker command?

Using Docker with Windows Paths
Docker uses the dot notation (:) as container name and path separator.
Consider the following Docker command:
docker cp D:\site\spering-html webserver:/usr/share/nginx/html

In this case, Docker attempts to resolve the command by looking for a container named "D" and trying to copy its internal contents from "\site\spering-html". However, since there is no container named "D", an error is thrown.
Solution
To resolve this issue, you can modify the command to wrap the Windows path in double quotation marks, like this:
docker cp "D:\site\spering-html" webserver:/usr/share/nginx/html

Here, you force the Docker interpreter to treat the the first argument as a (Windows/filesystem) path, rather than a container name. Also as you know the second one(i.e. webserver:/usr/share/nginx/html) is the container name and path inside it.
Additional Resources
For more information on this topic, you can refer to the following related answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49393168/7508077

